# Failed to handle SIBUS in JNI

Tags: android

My application crash due to SIGBUS inside library(I cannot get source code of that library)

zygote shows message:

"I/Zygote  (  179): Process 8824 exited due to signal (7)"

so i created sigbus handler as follows.

1.

```
    void sigbus_handler(void)
    { printf("SIGBUS CATCH\n"); }
```

2.

```
    act.sa_sigaction = sigbus_handler
    /* clear blocking mask */
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    /* option */
    act.sa_flags = SA_NOCLDSTOP | SA_RESETHAND | SA_ONSTACK | SA_SIGINFO;
    rc = sigaction(SIGBUS, &act, &old_act);
```

but couldn`t handle SIGBUS, only Zygote shows me SIGBUS message.
then, I sent signal using kill() function. like this:

```
    kill(getpid(), SIGBUS);
```

and surprisingly, this signal is handled within my handler:

V/sigbus_handler( 9279): SIGBUS CATCH

so what i am curious is why can`t i catch SIGBUS that created inside library? How only Zygote can notice that signal?

i think it doesn't matters whether signal was created in my source code function or library function. Both 2 SIGBUS should be handled same within my handler because all of them are in same process context. ;(

Comment: It seems we cannot catch sigbus using signal or sigaction because of zygote.